# No wireless cards found when attempting to use fluxion

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

Recently I have installed fluxion on my Pi 2. There wasn't any problem in the installation process, but when I tried to use fluxion, (after choosing the language) I got the message no wireless cards found ....

It is strange because I was able to see `wlan0` (and also connect to the internet) before I had selected language. And also the light on my Wi-Fi dongle goes off.

Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I could solve the problem. I bought a new wireless usb adapter. For those who are curious I will introduce model of the device. I purchased `TP-Link TL-WN722N` which is suitable for hacking tools in raspberry pi. It also supports monitor mode. For more information you can visit the official website.